# Why does NUnit expect an older version of the framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

This is the first time I'm attempting to use NUnit.  I've installed NUnit into my Visual Studio project, using NuGet.  As you can see in the image below, it references nunit.framework, version 2.6.1.12217...

[image: Visual Studio project]

... then I installed the latest Windows app (NUnit-2.6.1.msi)....

[image: Windows App]

... and tried to load my test assembly...

[image: Load fail]

... but for some reason, it's expecting version 2.5.10.11092 of nunit.framework.

Any idea if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Open up the project file, inspect the XML and ensure that the right path for the NUnit reference is set.

Comment: The path in the XML looks fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is that you are referencing a third party assembly that has a reference on a specific version of nunit.framework.

For example I encountered the same issue because I had a reference to `TeamAgile.UnitTestExtensions.dll`

To check if a particular assembly has a reference to nunit.framework.dll use ILDASM and check the `extern` metadata in the `MANIFEST`.

[image: Screenshot of ILDASM]

As you can see from the screenshot, this assembly has a reference to version 2.4.6 of nunit.framework.

To resolve this issue, add a binding redirect entry to the applications config file to map your old version to your new version.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="Neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.5.10.11092" newVersion="2.6.1.12217" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks Catch22.  I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but hopefully I'll get around to it within a week.

Comment: Unfortunately it was a long time ago that I tried this.  I tried again today, hoping to test your answer.  Everything worked fine, so I don't know what the problem was.  Your answer makes sense and it seems like it could have been my problem, so I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of your test projects (or a third party /project referenced by them) has a reference to that specific version. Inspect all csproj files that reference NUnit and look for a that version.

An easy way to make sure is to "search in files" for "*2.5.10.11092*" in *.csproj (I use notepad++ for that).

If there is no specific reference to the old version anywhere, it is possible that the old one is still in the GAC - Try to specifically reference the new version, and that should "win" against it.

EDIT - Reference example:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\ExternalLibrary\NUnit\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Hi Seldary.  Thanks for that.  I did a search and found two completely unrelated csproj files which reference that version.  I don't see how it matters though, seeing as they aren't related, aren't in the same solution, and compile to completely different locations.  Then I looked in C:\Windows\assembly and could not find nunit.framework.  So I added the new version (2.6.1.12217), and set my project to specifically reference that version... and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: One thing I found, which looks suspicious, is that in my NuGet package file I have <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net40" />, but in the NUnit GUI's about page it says "Framework Version: Net 3.5"

Comment: You shouldn't be adding dlls manually there... It matters because if the CLR loads that version first, then (if you don't reference a specific version) the CLR will use the loaded assembly and will not bother loading the assembly again. **Try removing the specific version from those projects** (see edit).

Comment: I have now deleted any projects that referenced the old version, and changed my project from <Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.6.1.12217, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL"> to <Reference Include="nunit.framework">... and I still get the same error.